# No tests found when filtering junit test suite

Tags: testing, gradle, filter, suite

I want to run a single junit4 test suite and specified it using filter in build.gradle ,but gradle(version 2.10) find no tests.
Is there a way to run a specified junit test suite in gradle?

My test suite class

```
    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ TestFoo.class, TestBar.class })
    public class MyTestSuite {

    }
```

build.gradle

```
    test {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*MyTestSuite"
        }
    }
```

Comment: The same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719406/gradle-test-task-does-not-run-junit-test-with-category-and-runwith-annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in the [DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) uses `include` instead:

```
test {
  // explicitly include or exclude tests
  include 'org/foo/**'
  exclude 'org/boo/**'
}
```

Comment: Yes,include works.(in my case  by adding the line include '**/MyTestSuite.class').Filter just does not work with junit test suite?

Answer (score 0):

filter is probably meant to be used in combination with include and exclude. [Doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html) says: Allows filtering **tests for execution**.

So if you would like to run just a single method foo:

```
test {
  include '**MyTestSuite.class'
  filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*TestBar.foo"
  }
}
```